# Error while importing a channel route

Tags: django

I am trying to build a chat app using `django channels`. I ran into this error and can't manage to solve it.

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import channel routing %r: %s" % (routing, e))
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import channel routing 'flamingo.routing.channel_routing': 'module' object has no attribute 'channel_routing

here is my settings.py file

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
>SECRET_KEY = '=ee2q)ew^@d(6v$3+@dt#jm9j@6eck-*+fu#b(v$to1dspe&l-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'chat',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'flamingo.urls'

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')

# Channel layer definitions
# http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying.html#setting-up-a-channel-backend
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "flamingo.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'flamingo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/




LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 1):

did you install channels?

`pip install channels==1.1.5`

if yes... try to install and runserver with python3

`pip3 install channels==1.1.5`

`python3 manage.py runserver`

I remember that i had already encountered that problem, but there were so many problems besides that Its hard for me to remember..

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this specified versions to get sure its working

pip3 freeze 
django==1.11.10 
channels==1.1.5

i test this items on my system and it works correct.